# How to split a list separated by ";" into sub lists in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I need to split one list, delimited by `;`, into multiple sub lists. Can I do it without converting it into an array in ColdFusion?

Example: My_list contains:

```
[10043,10044,10045,10046:2,5,3,1;3453,2167:1,0;2346,8674,9043,7543,6453:0,4,2,0,1]
```

I need:

```
My_list1 = [10043,10044,10045,10046:2,5,3,1]
My_list2 = [3453,2167:1,0]
My_list3 = [2346,8674,9043,7543,6453:0,4,2,0,1]
```

... and so on.

Comment: I'm curious, what benefit are you trying to gain from dynamic variable names instead of using an array?

Comment: Actually I have a complex calculation At DB level and these data are coming in this format from DB level & I need to separate the list first By ";" separated lists and then combine all those values into a single list with ":" separated values.

Comment: EX:- My Final List would be:Final_list = [10043,10044,10045,10046,3453,2167,2346,8674,9043,7543,6453:2,5,3,1,1,0,0,4,2,0,1]. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to "do" anything. A list is just a delimited string. So if you want to set those (very poorly named, IMO) variables, it's just a matter of:

```
<cfset fullList = "10043,10044,10045,10046:2,5,3,1;3453,2167:1,0;2346,8674,9043,7543,6453:0,4,2,0,1">
<cfset varIndex = 0>
<cfloop index="subList" list="#fullList#" delimiters=";">
    <cfset "My_list#++varIndex#" = subList>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#variables#">
```

I seriously wouldn't use dynamic variable names like that though, I'd use an array.

Comment: Personally, I prefer using associative array notation and the variables scope ie `<cfset variables["My_list"& ++varIndex] = subList>`. Though technically it makes no difference. That said ... I agree it seems unnecessary. What is the reasoning here?

Comment: Thanks for Answer..But I want as follows--My Final List would be:Final_list = [10043,10044,10045,10046,3453,2167,2346,8674,9043,7543,6453:2,5,3,1,1,0,0,4,2,0,‌​1]. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: That's a different question from the one you asked! Revise your question. Also explain the relationship between the first list and the last list.